# React Native - App Build Failed on XCode (RNTextDetector)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working on my company's old React Native project and trying to run the app on the simulator.

These are the steps what I have done in order:

1. I checked out the code from git
2. Run command `npm install` to install node_modules
3. go into ios folder and run `pod install` to create Pods folder
4. Open XCode and run the app

At the 4th step, the app was almost successfully built but then the errors occured in file `RNTextDetector.m` (the path is `{Root}/node_modules/rn-text-detector/ios/RNTextDetector.m`). Most of them are "Use of undeclared identifier 'xxx'". Here are the errors:

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "expo-local-authentication": "^12.1.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.137.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1267.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.35.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.32.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.24",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-text-detector": "0.0.8",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After I looked into RNTextDetector's original repository (rn-text-detector), I found this [thread](https://github.com/ashrithks/rn-text-detector/pull/5) and try following their code and it works!

The solution is to add `@import MLKitTextRecognitionCommon;` in file `RNTextDetector.m` as shown below:

```
#import "RNTextDetector.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@import MLKitTextRecognitionCommon;
@import MLKitTextRecognition;
@import MLKitVision;

@implementation RNTextDetector
...
```